# CentOS 7 - Payara 5 fails to run on Port 80

Tags: centos7, payara

I installed Paraya 5(.193) on CentOS 7 server and the installation is a success. Since I aim to host a JEE website on it, I changed the default http port (of Payara) from 8080 to 80 (after disabling apache web server in order to keep the port 80 free). However, when I rerun Payara (with Port 80 as a default one), I get the following error -

```
-- Unit payara.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 20 14:39:42 server1.gdfnow.org systemd[1]: Unit payara.service entered failed state.
Nov 20 14:39:42 server1.gdfnow.org systemd[1]: payara.service failed.
Nov 20 14:39:42 server1.gdfnow.org polkitd[541]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:16831:1426530 (system bus name :1.137, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disc
Nov 20 14:39:44 server1.gdfnow.org unix_chkpwd[16992]: password check failed for user (root)
Nov 20 14:39:44 server1.gdfnow.org sshd[16990]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=115.88.201.58  user=root
Nov 20 14:39:44 server1.gdfnow.org sshd[16990]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Nov 20 14:39:46 server1.gdfnow.org sshd[16990]: Failed password for root from 115.88.201.58 port 51698 ssh2
Nov 20 14:39:46 server1.gdfnow.org sshd[16990]: Received disconnect from 115.88.201.58 port 51698:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Nov 20 14:39:46 server1.gdfnow.org sshd[16990]: Disconnected from 115.88.201.58 port 51698 [preauth]
lines 1101-1128/1128 (END)
```

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

PS - In the error log, I have no clue what this IP Address of 115.88.201.58. It is certainly not a Public IP of my client computer.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check that you followed the steps e.g. in this tutorial: https://ahmermansoor.blogspot.com/2019/05/install-payara-server-5-on-centos-7.html Also, maybe there is more information in the `server.log` of Payara? Edit: I think the lines in the error log (except the first two) are not related to the Payara service itself.

Comment: P.S.: Someone using that IP seems to be scanning your server. See
https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/115.88.201.58

Comment: @ChristophJohn. Thanks for your help. I had indeed followed the link that you have mentioned above. Also, I agree that someone might be scanning the server and I have seen the second link as well. But having said that, I tried to simulate the same scenario on my localhost (switching port from 8080 to 80), and it works perfectly OK as I would expect. Reckon, I need to tighten the security on my server. Thanks again.